# pandas get business days data from datetime index

Tags: python, pandas

I have pandas dataframe as:

```
df.ix[1:4]
                     Data
DateTime                    
2015-05-24 02:00:00  4368.02
2015-05-24 03:00:00  4254.63
2015-05-24 04:00:00  4167.88
```

I have created a calendar as:

```
us_bd = CustomBusinessDay(calendar=myCalendar())
```

How do I extract the business days data and non business days data from `df`?

Right now I am extracting the dates from `df` and then checking their presence in `us_bd` using `numpy.in1d` which appears very clumsy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd simply say a business day is such that adding and subtracting one business day returns to the same day.

```
df['is_biz'] = ((df.DateTime + us_bd) - us_bd ) == df.DateTime
```

Comment: Unless July 4 or Dec 25 falls on Tuesday?

Comment: that should work I think. it depends on what dates you have on your custom calendar